mitmproxy: connection is closed when m4a file is hooked
I'm trying to download preview audio (m4a) files from Tunefind.
I set up localhost:8080 on Windows, install mitmproxy and .cer file from here http://mitm.it/
But when it capture audio file my proxy server block internet connection so I need to disable proxy
(I set up )
LOG
[::1]:56371: POST http://149.154.167.255/api
          << 200 OK 88b
[::1]:56371: POST http://149.154.167.255/api
          << 200 OK 88b
[::1]:56308: GET https://api-v2.tunefind.com/forward?action=p0BNXDJVzXlSljXRu6G7CScvPiHm%252FLEFVIhMahaF%252FBui… HTTP/2.0
 << HTTP/2.0 302 Found 0b
[05:41:54.777][[::1]:56390] client connect
[::1]:56371: POST http://149.154.167.255/api
          << 200 OK 88b
[::1]:56371: POST http://149.154.167.255/api
          << 200 OK 88b
[05:41:58.031][[::1]:56390] server connect audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com:443 (23.12.105.227:443)
[::1]:56371: POST http://149.154.167.255/api
          << 200 OK 88b
[05:41:58.200] Intercettato file audio: https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview125/v4/97/c9/b7/97c9b734-f2a7-c05d-88c9-6799dc358553/mzaf_1452710730924593330.plus.aac.p.m4a

I use a python script to run with proxy
mitmdump -s tunefind_proxy.py --listen-port 8080 --set console_eventlog_verbosity=debug
Content of script is this
from mitmproxy import http
import os
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

save_dir = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\scripts\\tunefind\\downloads"
os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.method == "GET":
        url = flow.request.pretty_url
        if "audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com" in url and url.endswith(".m4a"):
            logging.info(f"Intercettato file audio: {url}")
            download_audio(url)

def download_audio(url):
    try:
        logging.debug(f"Tentativo di download del file: {url}")
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
        response.raise_for_status()

        file_name = os.path.basename(url)
        logging.debug(f"Nome del file estratto: {file_name}")

        save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, file_name)
        logging.debug(f"Percorso completo del file: {save_path}")

        with open(save_path, 'wb') as file:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                file.write(chunk)
        logging.info(f"File salvato: {save_path}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Errore durante il download del file: {e}")

I try to understand if there is a way to download tunefind audio preview using script. Usually you need manually press on play button and then you see the url in Network Tab of browser

How large is the m4a file? mitmproxy first loads the content of each request/response to RAM before forwarding it to the real destination.

@Robert very small, usually less than 1.5mb, they are 30 second files

Looking closely at your code I find it strange: you have a program that loads files and you intercept those requests/responses for getting the file data. But instead of simply saving the downloaded data that passes mitmproxy you try to manually download the same URL (ignoring that there can be important headers) when you see it. Why don't you simply dump the data passing mitmproxy?
